# I need to share an object with many other objects - I've read complaints about singletons, so what should I use instead?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I have a Java application with several JFrame windows which all derive from a class called BaseWindow. Each of these windows needs to access a NetworkConnection object to send messages to a server. So I implemented the NetworkConnection object as a singleton and in the BaseWindow class I give each window a reference to it using

```
NetworkConnection networkConnectinon = NetworkConnection.getInstance();
```

And this is working fine. But if it is not good practise these days to use singletons I want to change it. So what should I replace it with?

Comment: The Singleton pattern is problem ONLY in some environments in specific cases - mostly on servers in complicated architectures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static `getInstance()` approach makes it harder to test your application, because you can't replace the `NetworkConnection` with a mock object, or use a fresh NetworkConnection instance for each unit test.

It might be better for your main class to inject the NetworkConnection object into each JFrame via their constructors - and create a NetworkConnection interface so you can either use a real NetworkConnection or a mock one.

This is the Dependency Injection pattern.

Note that your real NetworkConnection *could* still be a Singleton, if necessary - it's just a different way of providing it to objects that need it.

Comment: Yeah Im familiar with DI from C# and WPF. Ill add the NetworkConnection through DI so, I imagine it should still be a singleton though as there should only be one network connection.

Answer (score 1):

> But if it is not good practise these days to use singletons ...

I keep reading statements to that effect, but I somehow never get to read anything that says why. The Singleton pattern is an essential building block. Like any other, it can be abused. That's not in itself a reason for not using it.

Comment: @deporter No it isn't. The OP said '*if* it is not good practise these days to use singletons I want to change it'. Refuting the premiss voids the conclusion, and thus provides the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with the singleton in your case, and what's the problem in that pattern,.?
all of the windows shpuld use the same instance if they target to the same server, provide methods required in the class where the connection will be instantiated in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound interesting but you may have several `NetworkConnection` objects instead, seems like a connection pooling approach:

```
public class NetworkConnection
{
    private static NetworkConnection[] connections;
    private static int size = 10;

    private NetworkConnection()
    { /*Constructor*/ }

    public static NetworkConnection getConnection(int index)
    {
        if (connections == null) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                connections[i] = new NetworkConnection();
        }
        if (index < size)
            return connections[index];
        return null;
    }
}
```

And you may use a different connection for each of your JFrame windows, e.g. `NetworkConnection.getConnection(3);`

Comment: I think that would be a waste of resources and is adding complexity, only one NetworkConnection is ever needed at a particular time. NetworkConnection encapsulates a socket connected to a server and I only want one socket to connect from the client.